# Change Octopack nuget version numbers to teamcity's build number

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, nuget, teamcity-7.0, octopus-deploy

I Created an Octopack nuget package of an asp.net mvc website using team-city. 
I also added build parameters i.e  for package version numbers to use  team-city's  build number `%build.number%` and not the default as in AssemblyInfo.cs However my package numbers still come up as 1.0.0.0 regardless of the build parameters that I set.

I have tried  to use the .* in AssemblyInfo.cs which  auto generates version numbers but I would like to use  team-city's build  numbers as I have defined  them .

Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paul Stovell created a TeamCity plugin.  You can read about it [here](http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/integration/teamcity).

Once you have that installed, you should configure your build step to look like this:

[image]

Comment: I Have  tried to install  the plugin  following the instructions as in the link above, but when I restart the teamcity server it doesn't seem to extract the contents  of the zip file or is there an alternative method for this ?

Comment: I have been able  to get around the issue  I was having with package  version numbers  by using the AssemblyInfo Patch  that ships with  Teamcity.

Comment: Make sure you unblock the zip before depositing it on the correct location.  TeamCity will do the right thing if UAC doesn't get in the way.

Comment: @lacoder You may have some luck by setting the Compatibility of the tomcat.exe and tomcatw.exe to Administrator for all users.  That solved all access denied and plugin expanding problems as well as server restart issues...at least for my server.  I think many others experience this issue as well:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23075#comment=27-366878

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-26517#comment=27-473243

Good luck.